# The php8apache2_4.dll module is not loaded. I've been trying all day to fix this error, but I've failed

Tags: php

After using the command httpd -k install using the administrator mode of cmd, I tried to run the apache server through the command httpd -k start . However, these errors are displayed and the server is not running.

```
C:\php-8>httpd -k start
httpd: Syntax error on line 539 of C:/Apache/httpd-2.4.56-win64-VS17/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/php-8/php8apache2_4.dll into server: \xc1\xf6\xc1\xa4\xb5\xc8 \xb8\xf0\xb5\xe2\xc0\xbb \xc3\xa3\xc0\xbb \xbc\xf6 \xbe\xf8\xbd\xc0\xb4\xcf\xb4\xd9.
```

This is the error message from cmd. I saw this message and figured out that the problem was with line 539 of the httpd.conf file, so I looked at that line.

```
PHPIniDir "C:/php-8" 
LoadModule php_module "C:/php-8/php8apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

What existed on line 539 was `LoadModule php_module "C:/php-8/php8apache2_4.dll".`
That part was the cause of the error.

I thought it was a file path problem and looked at various parts such as the process name and file path, but the error still occurred. Also, I thought it was a problem because the file called 'php8apache2_4.dll' was not in my directory, so I downloaded a new file and inserted it into the location, but it just failed again. Please help me.

Since this is my first time posting a question, please let me know if there is any problem with the question. Also, I'm really sorry for using a translator because I live abroad.

Answer (score 0):

Download PHP **VS16 x64 Thread Safe** from official page
https://windows.php.net/download/

This package contain **php8apache2_4.dll**

Don't download **php8apache2_4.dll** from other source. It can be other version, or x86